# sony wh-1000xm4 configure high quality mic and audio output with bluetooth ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, headset, sony

I've just bought a Sony wh-1000xm4. I want to use audio output and microphone (headset) with the best possible audio quality for work calls (zoom, google meet, etc).
The device connected automatically in the first start, and I can hear really good audio with this configuration:

[image: A2DP Sink]

Then, when I configure to use the Sony wh-1000xm4 microphone for calls, the audio sounds horrible but the mic works:

[image: HSP/HFP]

I've read that A2DP Sink doesn't have a mic input mode.
Is it any other way to configure both audio output and the microphone in a good audio quality configuration?
This is my setup:

- My laptop is a ThinkPad L15 Gen 2 (15" Intel).
- Connectivity • WLAN + Bluetooth: RTL8852AE 11ax, 2x2 + BT5.2
- My Ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: It should work with the latest version of Ubuntu. There's been improvements in Pulseaudio and bluetooth support.

Comment: Do you mean 21.10?

Comment: Yes, see the section on "Ubuntu Desktop" in the [21.10 release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951). I'm on Arch Linux, with the new version of Pulseaudio and my Bluetooth headphones sound much better now in calls

Comment: What version of pulseaudio and bluetooth do you have?

Comment: Pulseaudio 0.15 (same as Ubuntu 20.10) and BlueZ 5.62 (slightly newer than Ubuntu).

Comment: Is it possible to update pulseaudio to 0.15 in ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Hi, I still have the exact same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and WH-1000XM4.

Comment: @mabz Do you have pulseaudio v 0.15 or higher?

Comment: Hi @eduardosufan , I have pulseaudio 15.99.1 (I just ran "pulseaudio --version").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now the answer is sadly: No. Your operating system needs to choose a [Bluetooth profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles).
HFP is the standard for using the microphone. This is also mentioned in [Sony documentation](https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/wh1000xm3/v1/en/contents/TP0001703113.html).

So it is some kind of Bluetooth technology problem.
This is also answered in detail in https://superuser.com/questions/1101560/bluetooth-handsfree-better-quality